# code igniter php null values get submitted to mysql DB as zeros (0)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am submitting data from an html form to a code igniter PHP backend, and null values get submitted to the database as zeros. Is there anyway to prevent this from happening (leave the database fields empty if the form field was empty?)

VIEW

```
<?php echo form_open('control_form/add_all'); ?>
<label for="f_membername">Member Name<span class="red">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="f_membername"/>
<?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit'); ?>
```

CONTROLLER

```
function add_all(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('f_membername', 'Member Name', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
    {
        #Add Member to Database
        $this->Model_form->add_all();
        $this->load->view('view_inc_header');
        $this->load->view('view_form_success');
        $this->load->view('view_inc_footer');
    }
}
```

MODEL

```
function add_all(){
    $v_membername = $this->input->post('f_membername');

    $data = array(

            'member_name' => $v_membername

    );

    $this->db->insert('members', $data);
}
```

The fieldtype in MySQL for most fields is tinytext, and the default value is "NONE"

Comment: What type is the database field in question, and does it have a default value?

Comment: I haven't done anything to specify a default value for any of the fields - all of my fields post as zeros if they're blank, whether they are text fields, numbers, serialized arrays, etc.

Comment: Can you show the coding part?

Comment: Ever find a solution to this? or what was causing the problem? Having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your empty form input fields are not NULL but empty strings '', so they are converted to 0 if the field type is INT. To insert NULL values just replace '' with NULL values in model/controller.

Comment: But they show up as zero if they're text too. Is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

I think the field type in your database is `INT`. If you insert `null` data into a `INT` field it will be converted to `0`(zero).

Comment: the fieldtype is, in most cases, tinytext or varchar

Answer (score 0):

Is any of your form validations running any usage of **substr()** ?
i.e.:

```
substr(trim('SOME_FORM_VALUE'),0,7)
```

I was having a similar problem and it was definitely because **substr()** was returning FALSE or 0.